# Can I create a collection of arbitrary types in F#?

Tags: collections, f#

Very simple

```
let x = dict [(1, "Foo"); (2, 4)]
```

doesn't work. So I hoped that this will work.

```
let x:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int,System.Object> = dict [(1, "foo"); (2, 4)]
```

Also doesn't. I sort of understand ...

But then how do I process a collection (of arbitrary types) that was handed over to me from an external library?

```
let x = SomeCallToAExternalLibraryReturningArbitraryTypes()
```

Answer (score 0):

F# is strongly typed. You need to cast your objects to the correct type. If you want to have tuples of int * obj then:

```
[(1, "Foo" :> obj); (2, 4 :> obj)] |> dict
```

Comment: `box` is idiomatic here.